# How do I add commons-logging to my build.sbt file?

Tags: java, sbt, apache-commons-logging

What do I put in my build.sbt file to fix this?

```
[warn]  module not found: commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jay/.ivy2/local/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   file:/Users/jay/local/activator-1.3.2-minimal/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/commons-logging-99.0-does-not-exist.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/commons-logging-99.0-does-not-exist.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/commons-logging/commons-logging/99.0-does-not-exist/commons-logging-99.0-does-not-exist.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist: not found
```

I've tried all of the following, non of them work:

```
"commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "99.0-does-not-exist",
"commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2",
"commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1",
```

I get this error when I add the line:

```
"com.google.code.geocoder-java" % "geocoder-java" % "0.16"
```

This is my build.sbt:

```
name := """cxo-enricher"""

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, GitVersioning)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaWs,
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.10.12",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.10.12",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sqs" % "1.10.12",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20141113",
  "de.malkusch.whois-server-list" % "public-suffix-list" % "2.0.1",
  "com.timgroup" % "java-statsd-client" % "3.0.1",
  "com.google.code.geocoder-java" % "geocoder-java" % "0.16"
)

Commons.settings

dockerRepository := Some("XXXX")

version in Docker := "latest"
```

Comment: So using `"commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2"` only didn't work? If not post the errors you got (in your error log sbt complains that `99.0-does-not-exist` does not exists and well, it is right...). Also have you run `reload` and `update` in the sbt shell after the changes?

Comment: @Salem Correct, "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2", does not fix it. I get the same error. I run it with: activator clean compile

Comment: Can you show build.sbt? I just managed to successfully compile an Activator project both with commons-logging 1.2 and 1.1.1. They are both visible in public https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/

Comment: Geocoder 0.16 has a transitive dependency on commons-logging 1.2 which is definitely there in maven1. When you say you have tried all the following - do you mean you did have them as entries in libraryDependencies once  and have since removed them?

Comment: @Nio Yes, it means I put those lines in my libraryDependencies ++= Seq() list and I still got the error. It is insisting on commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist. It doesn't seem satisfied by 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commons-logging#commons-logging;99.0-does-not-exist is a dummy implementation that does nothing.

Try adding the JBoss repo to the list of resolvers in your build.sbt (this is where 99.0-does-not-exist is hosted) - the following worked for me - compiled successfully.

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
        "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
        "JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/"
)
```

If you need another version of commons-logging in your lib then you can still declare 1.2, for example, in your list of dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2",
  "com.google.code.geocoder-java" % "geocoder-java" % "0.16",
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)
```

When you build the project SBT will warn you that it has evicted 99.0-does-not-exist - which is fine.